# Find the integral $\int_{c(0,1)}\frac{c_0+c_1z+.........+c_{2n}z^{2n}}{z^{n+1}}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, cauchy-integral-formula

By considering the case when p = −1 separately find

$$\int_{c(0,1)}z^p  dz$$

$c(0,1)$ means a circle around the origin of radius 1

where p ∈ $\mathbb{Z}$ and hence if n ∈ $\mathbb{N}$ ∪ {0} and $c_0,c_1,.........,c_{2n}∈ \mathbb{C} find$

$$\int_{c(0,1)}\frac{c_0+c_1z+.........+c_{2n}z^{2n}}{z^{n+1}}dz$$

so I evaluating at p=-1 to get the formula for every $z^{-1}$ which is $$\int_{c(0,1)} \frac{c_n}{z}dz$$

but I don't how how to take this any further or if this is even the right direction to go in. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does $c(0,1)$ mean? Also, you have commas in your integral, e.g. $c_0,c_1z,\ldots$, what do those mean?

Comment: c(0,1) is because it is a path integral a circle with an origin of 0 and a radius of 1

Comment: and the commas are meant to be plus signs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is good so far - now you just need to evaluate the last integral. Parametrize the contour as $\gamma(t) = e^{it}$, $t\in[0,2\pi)$ (assuming $c(0,1)$ is oriented counterclockwise), and use the usual definition of contour integration:
$$
\int_\Gamma f(z)~dz = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)~dt.
$$

Comment: ok so following that method I got  $2i\pi c_n$ for my $z^{-1}$ formula is that the solution to both parts?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by both parts, but that is indeed the value of the last integral in your post. Hopefully you can take it from here.

Comment: sorry for the confusion I was asking if that answer was also the answer to $\int_{c(0,1)}\frac{c_0+c_1z+.........+c_{2n}z^{2n}}{z^{n+1}}dz$ and if it was not how would I find that from here

Comment: Well, $\int_{c(0,1)} z^pdz = 0$ for all $p\neq -1$, which I assumed you knew based on your post. Hopefully you already know why this is true, and with that you should have all the ingredients to work out every integral you're interested in here.